# How to pass combo box selected value and radio button list checked value from view to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I have a view with kendo combo boxes and radio button list and text box and i want to pass the combo box selected value and radio button checked value from view to controller via json object.
I have done half work. I am able to pass the value of textbox, combo box selected index(but I need selected text).
How can I pass all these value as a single object?

here is my code

```
$('#btnSelect').click(function () {
    var inputparam = {
        NameOperator: $('#cmbNameOperator').val(),
        Name: $('#txtSmaple').val(),
        Address: $("#txtAddress").val(),
        City: $("#txtCity").val(),
        State: $("#cmbProvinceOperator").val(),
        PostalCode: $("#txtPostalCode").val(),
        Country: $("#cmbCountryOperator").val()

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Select", "Search", new { area = "Search" })',
        type: "POST",
        data: inputparam,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success " + result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error " + err);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you send the data as json, do stringify first, like

```
data: JSON.stringify(inputparam),
dataType: "json",
```

**UPDATE**

To get the value of drop down box you can use.

```
$('#yourComboxId:selected').text();
```

You can get value of checked radio button like this

```
var radioVal =  $('input:radio[name=yourRadioName]:checked').val();
```

Comment: my code is working but i am not able to get the combo box selected text, i am getting combo box selected value also how to get the radio button checked value?

Comment: my sample cshtml code is  <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("lblPostalCode", "Postal Code", )
                                <div>
                                        @Html.TextBox("txtPostalCode", "", new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
                                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
            .Name("cmbPostalOperator")
            .BindTo(new List<string>(){
                "Contains","Start With","Exact"
               
            })
            .SelectedIndex(1)
            
            )
                                </div>

Comment: <div>
                                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                                {

                                    @Html.Label("lblStatus", "Status")
                                    <label class="checkbox inline">
                                        @Html.RadioButton("Status", "Active", true) Active
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        @Html.RadioButton("Status", "Inactive", false) Inactive
                                    </label></div>

Comment: please have a look udpated answer for get value after checked on radio.

Answer (score 1):

1) to get the combobox text you can simply use:

```
$("#cmbCountryOperator option:selected").text()
```

2) If all of your controls are inside of a form, you can serialize them to the string:

```
$('#myForm').serialize()
```